# Linear mixed effects model. Two independent groups and six measures

Tags: r, mixed-model, interpretation

I am currently working on a study regarding a psychotherapeutic intervention for anxiety. In my dataset I have:

- Two groups: experimental vs control
- 6 time points
- dependent variable (DV): anxiety

I need to see if levels of anxiety changed significantly during time in the experimental condition, in comparison with the baseline and the control group.

The solution for the model seems to be this:

```
model<-lmer("anxiety~factor(time)*factor(group)+(time|username)", data)
```

But, I have trouble interpreting the results. What confuses me is that in the row "Estimate" the first value (for Intercept) is basically the mean of timepoint 1 in group 1 (adjusted for the random effects in this case). Then, all further values represent the differences between the current value and the intercept (e.g. estimate in second raw: -1.4449 = factor(time)2-(Intercept)).

All seems good by now, but estimates for control group are also presented as differences between the current value and Intercept for the experimental condition. There must be a reason, but I can't see why someone would want to compare changes in control group with the baseline in the experimental.

***How could I set the model so that the comparison in the control group is made with the intercept for the control group?***

Regarding t values ***What does the t value for (Intercept) and factor(grup)2 show?***
For example, in my understanding, -2.748 (t value in raw 2) represents the difference between anxiety in **group 1 time 1** (intercept) and **group 1 time 2**. From this perspective, the t value for the intercept doesn't seem to make sense.

```
Fixed effects:
                              Estimate  Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                    8.0601     0.4343   18.560
factor(time)2                 -1.4449     0.5258   -2.748
factor(time)3                 -2.6103     0.5643   -4.625
factor(time)4                 -3.1484     0.6397   -4.921
factor(time)5                 -3.6304     0.6718   -5.404
factor(time)6                 -3.2011     0.9446   -3.389
factor(group)2                -0.2209     0.7694   -0.287
factor(time)2:factor(group)2   0.9396     0.9314    1.009
factor(time)3:factor(group)2   1.4870     0.9833    1.512
factor(time)4:factor(group)2   2.1079     1.0818    1.949
factor(time)5:factor(group)2   2.3289     1.0806    2.155
factor(time)6:factor(group)2  -0.7829     1.5175   -0.516
```

I would by highly grateful I someone could help me clarify these points.
P.S. Sorry for combining 2 questions in a one post. They seemed highly related.

Comment: t value = estimate/standard error for each row in the output data. It doesn't represent a difference between something and the intercept. The t-value can be used to calculate a p-value which is the probability that the estimate assumes this value or a more extreme value given the null hypothesis (i.e. that a given estimate is 0). This is normally pointless to do for the intercept.